# What's the reason of getting Mysql 50000 rows from 4919 rows left join 4919 rows?

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT * FROM(
(SELECT A1.*, A2.ID2, A2.ID3, A2.TYPE1, A2.TYPE2, A2.TYPE3 FROM(
(SELECT A.ID, A.ID1, A.ID2, A.ID3, A.ID4,  B.ID5, B.ID6, B.ID7, B.ID8, B.ID8, B.ID9, B.ID10 from(
(SELECT ID, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4 FROM RECORD1) AS a left join
(SELECT ID, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7 FROM RECORD2) AS b 
ON a.ID = b.ID1)) as A1 left join
(select ID, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7, ID8, Type1, Type2, e.ttype3 as Type3 FROM(
(select ID, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7, ID8, BB.Type1, CC.D.type AS Type2 from(
(select ID, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7, ID8, BB.C.Type AS Type1 from(
(SELECT A.*, B.ID1, B.type, b.ID3, b.ID4, ID5 FROM(
(SELECT * FROM record) as a left join
(SELECT * FROM record2) as b on a.ID = b.ID1)) as AA left join
(SELECT Type, ID as ttype1 from record2 where Type='SMALL') as c on aa.id = c.ttype1)) as BB left join **strong text**
(SELECT Type, ID as ttype2 from record2 where Type='MEDIUM') as d on BB.id = d.ttype2)) as CC left join
(SELECT Type, ID as ttype3 from record2 where Type='LARGE') as e on cc.id = e.ttype3)) as A2
on A1.ID3 = A2.ID3)) as A3 left join   # A3 is the first part with 4919 rows
(SELECT a.ID1, a.ID2, b.ID3, b.ID4, b.ID5, b.ID6, b.ID7, b.ID8, b.ID9, b.ID1, b.ID2, b.ID3, b.ID4, b.ID5, b.ID6, b.ID7 from(
(SELECT * FROM record1) as a left join
(SELECT * FROM record3) as b on a.ID1 = b.ID)) AS A4 on A3.ID1 = A4.ID1) on A3.ID1 = A4.ID1)) AS A5 LEFT join #A4 has 4919 rows, and A5 has 50000 rows.
```

As shown in the comment, my question is how I got a result with 50000 rows after a left join of two 4919 rows?

Comment: What in the name of all that is holy...

Comment: How about I do you a huge favor.  Post your DDL, and what you're trying to do, and we'll work from there.

Comment: This SQL text has *way* more inline view queries, `SELECT` and `FROM` keywords, than would reasonably expected.

Comment: Thank you for the huge favour you offered Phillip :) but I am afraid I have to keep the data in perfect confidence really...

Comment: Alas, it's only a part of the whole thing I am trying to do... Spencer7593 :( I do wish I could have a neater and faster way to do this....

Comment: Whatever it is you are trying to do, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Nobody's asking for your private data. We're asking for the Data Description Language: the definitions of the columns of your tables. We're also asking for an explanation of the result set you need.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is extraordinarily hard to understand.  It's clear you're working with human health data, so it's critical that you reformat it to allow it to be inspected.

I suspect you have at least one `(LEFT) JOIN` clause without an `ON` qualifier. This will cause a combinatorial explosion, which gives you the extra rows.

Format your SQL so you can read your logic.  I suggest you use this sort of format.

```
       SELECT col, col, col
        FROM table AS a
   LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT thing, thing, thing
                FROM anotherTable
             ) AS b ON a.index = b.a_index AND b.criterion = 'Something'
   LEFT JOIN patient AS p ON p.id = a.id
```

Do you see how you can easily look at this kind of query, seeing the tables and subqueries that go into it?  Do you see how it can be inspected for accuracy?

I tried, and failed, to make sense of your query by reformatting it this way. You're the one who knows the logic, so it's up to you to do that.

(If you got this from another programmer, you have my condolences! But you still have to sort it out into a rational format.)

Comment: Big +1 for the importance of this being readable. Yeesh!

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! GREAT HELP!

Comment: @OllieJones: I tried to decipher it too. There's closing parens before I expect them, before the `ON` clause for the `JOIN`, and there's way too many opening parens... looks like way too many inline views (derived tables). And some of the inline view queries are just `(SELECT * FROM table)`... I gave up trying to figure it out. The query, as its currently constructed, is way more complex than it needs to be.